# I want to assign a switch (SW) to an input (D)

Tags: vhdl, master-slave

I am doing an exercise for my university with fpga's in VHDL code.I want to create master-slave D flip flop by calling a gated D Latch.I think my code is ok but the problem is that an error is occurring.The message says that I can't write to interface object "D" of mode IN.I want to assign switch"SW(0)" of the altera d2 board to D input and Clk to switch "SW(1)".Please I want to know the right way to do it.

```
BEGIN
D<=SW(0);
LEDR(0) <=D;
Clk <=SW(1);
LEDR(1) <=Clk;
LEDR(2) <=Q;

   G1: notGate port map(clk, invOut1);
   G2: notGate port map(invOut1, invOut2);
   G3: gdlatch port map(invOut1, D, Dout, dummy);
   G4: gdlatch port map(invOut2, Dout, Q, notQ);



END Structural;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get a useful answer if you follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Secondly, supply the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. This is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If `D` is an input, you can only read it, you are not allowed to assign to it (otherwise your input would be an output).

Comment: If I can't assign an input to a switch how am I supposed to give the "D" 0 or 1 ?

Comment: We need an MCVE.

Comment: What is this???

Comment: It's a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . I gave a link to it in my first comment.  You describe `D` as being an input; I suspect we might be talking at cross purposes. But the fact is, you haven't given enough information to enable me or anyone else to help you (and you've probably given some extraneous information, too, which might obscure the problem or, at the very least, deter someone from trying to help you, because they can't be bothered to plough through too much code).

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably about hierarchy.

So you have a **component** called a master-slave flipflop. Let's say it's described by:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dff is port(
    clk, rst, d : in std_logic;
    q : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture rtl of dff is begin
    q <= d and not rst when rising_edge(clk);
end architecture;
```

So that's a **closed design**. You don't add inputs inside of that: you use the entity interface. Comparably you would not connect your computer keyboard directly *inside* your CPU. Instead, you have a wrapper that handles the in and outputs.

In your case, you want a new entity which instantiates the `dff` component. E.g.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dff_wrapper is port(
    SW : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    LEDR : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture rtl of dff_wrapper is
    signal D, Q, Clk : std_logic;
begin
    D<=SW(0);
    LEDR(0) <=D;
    Clk <=SW(1);
    LEDR(1) <=Clk;
    LEDR(2) <=Q;

    dff_inst : entity work.dff port map (
        clk => Clk, d => D, q => Q);
end architecture;
```

See? Now your code works.

PS, in-circuit testing is generally not the way to go at it in VHDL. You want to be using test benches.